# Importing variables specified at __init__.py

Tags: python, import, init

The project structure is as follows:

```
proyect/
  run.py
  app/
     __init_.py
     file.py
```

`__init__.py` has:

```
# At __init__.py
app = "My var"
```

And I want to use the `app` variable inside `file.py`;  I'm doing:

```
# At file.py
from app import app
print app
```

But I get an: `"ImportError: No module named app"`

The variable is best situated at `__init__.py`, without changing that, how can I use `app` from `file.py`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Import it as you would import from a normal `.py` file, like below:

```
from __init__ import app
print app
```

Result:

```
My var
```

As it currently stands(`from app import app`), python would be looking for a module or file named `app` ***within*** the current working directory, which it obviously won't find, and so an `ImportError` will be thrown.

Comment: I haven't seen that kind of import (meaning: 'from __init__ import x') anywhere. Is it considered 'clean'?

Comment: @juyix FWIW, I haven't seen variables specified within `__init__.py`, and I am pretty sure creating a new file for such config variables would be considered much cleaner. But since you've them already specified, might as well import them in the way I've written.

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/version-0.14/app/__init__.py. There variables such as app, db and auth are declared.

Comment: I would actually suggest using relative imports instead specifically declaring `__init__` the location, i.e. `from . import app`

Comment: @justanr that throws up `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: @juyix Check https://github.com/zakx/tempmail/blob/master/smtpd.py , https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/blob/master/BitTornado/zurllib.py#L11 , https://github.com/Pylons/pylons/blob/master/tests/test_units/test_helpers.py#L8 , and https://github.com/elmom/pypsyc/blob/master/mjacob/old/pypsyc-twisted.py#L11 . All import from `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from `__init__.py` properly.

What are you running at your `bash` prompt to get that `ImportError`, and what are the contents of your `proyect/run.py` file?

If I have `proyect/run.py` contain the following:

```
from app import file
```

then running `proyect/run.py` from the command line gives me the expected result (printing `My var`). Trying to run `proyect/app/file.py` from the command line, though, gives me the error you describe.

In general, these import issues are a reason why I've heard in the past to keep any scripts a user might want to run in the root directory of your project (such as `proyect/run.py` here) rather than within subdirectories (such as `proyect/app/run.py`). I'm not entirely sure what Python internals lead to the difference in import semantics between the two, but this is what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing `proyect/__init__.py` (it can be empty) in order to make `proyect` a Python package.

Next, you need to use a relative import in `file.py`

```
from ..app import app
```

To understand why that particular syntax is needed, let's look at some incorrect imports and see what they would try to load:

- `from app import app` - load a module from `app.py` in the same directory as `file.py` (or if that fails, from the standard library)
- `from .app import app` - load a module from `app.py` in `proyect/app/` (same as the previous case, actually; this is just an explicit relative import which prevents the absolute import from being attempted)

Thus, `..app` goes up one directory further in the current project, and loads a module from `app.py` in `proyect/`.